# Silverlight Theme for a Business App

Tags: silverlight, themes

I'm working on a project in Silverlight that needs allot of data on the screen at one time. With some of the default silverlight themes I can take the font size down to about 11pt, but still the margins between the lines in a list or a grid box are just too large.

Does anyone know of a good theme for a business app? Something that allows for displaying large amounts of data in as small of a screen space as possible, while yet keeping legibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for pre-built themes, i would try out Telerik Silverlight Controls - http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx.

You always have the option of writing your own themes and opening blend and editing existing themes.

Also here are some themes: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/06/13/theme-pack-for-silverlight-business-application-released.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[The "JetPack" theme](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/09/silverlight-jetpack-theme-released.aspx) is a good base to start from.  It's part of the [Theme Pack for Silverlight Business](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/06/13/theme-pack-for-silverlight-business-application-released.aspx).

JetPack is not as bubbly as most themes, so if you switch out some of the colors, I think it could have a clean business look.